# Magento2 less modification command

Tags: magento2.2, less

Might this is basic query.
I am using "Pedona magento theme" for my website, now I need very small modification in style.less

`/app/design/frontend/pedona/pedona_default/web/css/style.less`

do have to run some command or it will automatically compose to style.css?

Magento2+

Comment: We need to push less commands.

Comment: @AnasMansuri, and what are those command and have to use SSH, as store is live and running on BlueHost server